# 503 Error on a single route after deploying to Heroku, other routes working normally

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I'm building a full stack application using React and Node and one of my API routes is giving me a 503 error after I deploy to Heroku despite working locally. For whatever reason, all my other routes work fine after deploying. For context, this used to be a group project I was working on, but I decided to refactor so it would function better. I've done little change to the server on my own and it was working fine when we previously deployed (issues were more on the React side).

I'm not entirely sure where in my code I've messed up so here's the github: https://github.com/H0sway/puppy-finder-app.

This is my app.js file. The route that's not working is /api/puppyfinder.

```
// Import dependencies
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
require('dotenv').config();

// Middleware stuffs
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use(express.static('build'));

//API route
app.use('/api/puppy', require('./routes/puppy-routes'));
app.use('/api/opinions', require('./routes/opinion-routes'));
app.use('/api/puppyfinder', require('./routes/puppy-finder-routes'));
app.get('/*', (req,res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'))
});

// Setting up the port
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Live on port ${PORT} but also it's the Shrek movie`);
});
```

And here's the method in the React component where I'm trying to call it.

```
// changes the redirect state so the component knows to redirect to the results page

handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Post to the puppyfinder controller, which will make a get request to the puppy finder API
    // Sends the breed and zipcode to the controller
    axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/api/puppyfinder',
      data: {
        breed: this.state.breed,
        zipcode: this.state.zipcode,
      },
    })
    // Checks to see if puppy data was returned by putting it into an array
    .then(puppyData => {
      console.log(puppyData.data.data.pet);
      if (puppyData.data.data.pet.length) {
        this.setState({
          puppiesLoaded: true,
          puppyData: puppyData.data.data.pet,
        });
      }
      else {
        alert(`Sorry, but we couldn't find any ${this.state.breed} dogs nearby ${this.state.zipcode}. Maybe try something else?`)
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('puppyfinder call error', err);
    })
  }
```

Edit: I've been looking through the heroku logs more closely and here's what I'm getting when I try to post to the server. This makes me think the issue might be in my controller, but it worked fine when I deployed as a group and I haven't changed that file since then. Still working locally too.

```
2018-04-03T16:43:30.656152+00:00 app[web.1]: inside puppy finder API call error TypeError: Cannot read property 'pets' of undefined
2018-04-03T16:43:30.656164+00:00 app[web.1]:     at axios.then.allTheDogs (/app/controllers/puppy-finder-controller.js:12:43)
2018-04-03T16:43:30.656169+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:118:7)
2018-04-03T16:43:30.656166+00:00 app[web.1]:     at <anonymous>
2018-04-03T16:44:00.622922+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/api/puppyfinder" host=fathomless-bayou-33817.herokuapp.com request_id=b008d8bd-750e-4681-89e5-7fcf1999dcfe fwd="100.12.160.42" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

Comment: look at your heroku server logs

Comment: Here's the error message I'm getting: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/api/puppyfinder" host=fathomless-bayou-33817.herokuapp.com request_id=b008d8bd-750e-4681-89e5-7fcf1999dcfe fwd="100.12.160.42" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https

Comment: I'm gonna edit the post with more details on the heroku logs.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, didn't set my private API key for the third party API I was using. Was set locally in my .env file but not on heroku. For future reference set anything you put into your .env file by using `$ heroku config:set VARIABLE=value`.